# my laptop is not charging when switched on

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery

I have an satellite l735-11f laptop and i have been facing a problem where the laptop battery does not charge even when power cable is plugged in.

I have noticed though that i am able to charge my battery if i follow these steps -

1. Switch off my laptop, unplug the power cable and take out the battery.
2. Wait for 2-3 seconds and put the battery back in
3. Connect the power cable while the laptop is off

As long as i do not switch on my laptop, my battery charges.

Comment: Are you using the original power cable? Often this kind of thing will happen if you use a 3rd party or alternate power cable for your machine.

Comment: Probably battery was damaged. How much time you were using your laptop with plugged cable?

Answer (score 0):

> As long as i do not switch on my laptop, my battery charges.

This says it all. Your charger doesn't have enough energy to power both battery charging circuit and laptop. If it is nit the original one try to replace it with another of the same voltage but a greater current (amperage).

If it is the original charger, then it is broken and can't supply the required current anymore.

Comment: Its the original charger only and i also tried with a new charger but problem persists

Comment: @user338286 but can you power on the laptop while on adapter and without battery?